# Get value of a row and display it in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a xml file with some data and i loaded it in a table(Oracle Database) using ETL(Oracle Data integrator).

the table contains the following data

```
id     student      class      scoreT1         scoreT2 
1      English       3-B       null             null
2      null          null      12/09/2014       18/09/2014
3      null          null        null            null
4      Jack          null        15.5             18
5      Richard       null        16               17
6      Jhon          null        17               14
7      French        5-B        null             null
8      null         null       12/09/2014       18/09/2014 
9      null         null        null            null
10     Cena         null        14.5            13
11     Mike         null        12              17
12     Philip       null        10              14
```

I need a select query to get  the resultant as below:

```
   id     student      class      scoreT1         scoreT2             val1         val2            val3          val4
    1      English       3-B       null             null              3-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     English 
    2      null          null      12/09/2014       18/09/2014        3-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     English
    3      null          null        null            null             3-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     English
    4      Jack          null        15.5             18              3-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     English
    5      Richard       null        16               17              3-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     English
    6      Jhon          null        17               14              3-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     English
    7      French        5-B        null             null             5-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     French
    8      null         null       12/09/2014       18/09/2014        5-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     French
    9      null         null        null            null              5-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     French
    10     Cena         null        14.5            13                5-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     French
    11     Mike         null        12              17                5-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     French
    12     Philip       null        10              14                5-B       12/09/2014       18/09/2014     French
```

i need a `SQL` statement or `PL/SQL` to get the result i don't know if it's possible

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you please add some detail around the columns you want to add and how they should be computed? Also add what you have tried so far.

Comment: So there are 6 rows for every student and its first row gives student / class details, second row gives dates, third row is empty and 4th-6th row gives you student data? I am assuming you are parsing XML to put data in this staging table. Believe me it is a not a good way. I would suggest you to change your ETL to parse data correctly rather than putting data in this format. What if you don't get 6 rows per subject?. What is one of that values is missing or something. Then your query would not behave correctly.

Comment: I believe, using XMLTYPE or XMLTABLE you could've actually done it easier and better.
How about creating another question where you could ask for help with parsing your XML?
As **Ultsav's** already written, data stored in your table can be really unpredictable or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try my solution:

```
with cte as (
      select 
        id,student,class,scoreT1,scoreT2,
        sum (case when class is not null then 1 else 0 end ) over (order by id) class_flag1,
        sum (case when class is not null then 0 else 1 end ) over (order by id) class_flag2,
        sum (case when scoreT1 like '__/__/____' then 1 else 0 end ) over (order by id) scoreT1_flag1,
        sum (case when scoreT1 like '__/__/____' then 0 else 1 end ) over (order by id) scoreT1_flag2
      from tab
    )
    select 
      a.id,a.student,a.class,a.scoreT1,a.scoreT2,
      nvl(first_value(a.class) over (partition by id - a.class_flag2 order by id),b.class) class_new,
      nvl(first_value(a.scoreT1) over (partition by id - a.scoreT1_flag2 order by id),c.scoreT1) scoreT1_new
    from cte a
    cross join (select min(class) keep (dense_rank first order by id) class from cte where class_flag1 = 1) b
    cross join (select min(scoreT1) keep (dense_rank first order by id) scoreT1 from cte where scoreT1_flag1 = 1) c
```

Comment: Missed two columns ,but you can refer the logic

Answer (score 0):

You can get `val1` using `lag()` with ignore nulls.  It is hard to see what the logic is for the last column.  However, I might guess that you are looking for a particular format in score T1.  So, this might do what you want:

```
select max(case when scoreT1 like '__/__/____' then scoreT1 end) over (partition by val1) as val2
from (select lag(class ignore nulls) over (order by id) as val1
      . . .
     ) t;
```